# Google Maps Javascript API new renderer (v3.32) infowindow displayed under controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps

With the Google Maps JS API new renderer, as of v3.32, infowindows placement seems wrong. They are not panned outside of map controls areas. The best example is directly from Google Maps Platform docs. If you go here and click on the marker you'll see what I'm talking about: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple
See bottom of question for printscreen.

I searched a lot for some information on this change of behavior, if that's by design now, in case we'd have to handle this in code, but can't seem to find anything regarding this. What would be the API way to deal with this ?

[image: Google Maps Javascript API infowindow placement]

Comment: @downvoter: question edited to the best of my knowledge, since you didn't care to comment on the problem with the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's partly been fixed in the weekly channel (current = 3.34). So you can load your map with `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.34&key=...`
and the infowindow should move out of the map control's areas. It seems though it will not pan out of custom controls areas, which it used to do before the new renderer.